# How to correctly get image from 'Resources' folder in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, resources

I have a Java Project in NetBeans 7.0.

I want to add some image to some label dynamically. The image will differ depending on the state of the program.

I put one such image, 'filling.jpg', in the 'resources' folder of my project.

I want to reach this file correctly (not by absolute or relative path, because that will cause problems when I build the jar file).

So I found this method:

```
ImageIcon fillingIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("filling.jpg"));
labelFontFilling.setIcon(fillingIcon);
```

It keeps give me java.lang.NullPointerException.
But I am sure that there is that image, because I can assign the image to the label from the NetBeans Properties menu for that label (but I don't want this, I want to add the image by Java code).

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get that image correctly?

Comment: can you print the path the is given ? Like System.out.println(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("filling.jpg")), this can give you a clue of the path that you are try to use.

Comment: It's return 'null', so that's a problem of Exeption. But i can't understand why it's return is null

Comment: and where is the resources folder created in your project ? is it in classpath?

Comment: It's resources folder in src/NameofProject/resources. It's created by default by NetBeans. I don't know how to add it to project, i look to Project->Properties->Libraies, but i can't find place, where i can add it.

Comment: there is good advice here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253066/debugging-getresource

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bundle images in jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273040/how-to-bundle-images-in-jar-file)

Comment: This solution worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749192/how-do-i-load-a-file-from-resource-folder

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thanks, **Valter Henrique**, with your tip i managed to realise, that i simply entered incorrect path to this image.
In one of my tries i use

```
    String pathToImageSortBy = "resources/testDataIcons/filling.png";
    ImageIcon SortByIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(pathToImageSortBy));
```

But correct way was use name of my project in path to resource

```
String pathToImageSortBy = "nameOfProject/resources/testDataIcons/filling.png";
ImageIcon SortByIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(pathToImageSortBy));
```

Answer (score 49):

This was a pain, using netBeans IDE 7.2.

1. You need to remember that Netbeans cleans up the Build folder whenever you rebuild, so
2. Add a resource folder to the **src** folder:

   - (project)

     - **src**

       - project package folder (*contains .java files*)
       - **resources**          (*whatever name you want*)
       - images (*optional subfolders*)
3. After the clean/build this structure is propogated into the Build folder:

   - (project)

     - build

       - classes

         - project package folder (*contains generated .class files*)
         - resources              (*your resources*)
         - images       (*your optional subfolders*)

To access the resources:

```
dlabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/images/logo.png")));
```

and:

```
if (common.readFile(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/allwise.ini"), buf).equals("OK")) {
```

worked for me. Note that in one case there is a leading "/" and in the other there isn't.
So the **root of the path to the resources** is the "**classes**" folder within the build folder.

Double click on the executable jar file in the dist folder. The path to the resources still works.

Comment: This is a little unclear to me. Is the images folder supposed to be inside the resources folder, or alongside it!

Answer (score 25):

I have a slightly different approach that might be useful/more beneficial to some.

Under your main project folder, create a resource folder.  Your folder structure should look something like this.

- Project Folder

  - build
  - dist
  - lib
  - nbproject
  - resources
  - src

Go to the properties of your project.  You can do this by right clicking on your project in the Projects tab window and selecting Properties in the drop down menu.

Under categories on the left side, select Sources.

In Source Package Folders on the right side, add your resource folder using the Add Folder button.  Once you click OK, you should see a Resources folder under your project.

[image]

You should now be able to pull resources using this line or similar approach:

```
MyClass.class.getResource("/main.jpg");
```

If you were to create a package called Images under the resources folder, you can retrieve the resource like this:

```
MyClass.class.getResource("/Images/main.jpg");
```

Comment: i used this method but i found a disturbing effect. after the build netbeans loads all the resources inside the jar, and i really want the resources to stay out of the jar! so is there a workaround for this problem ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the java resource method might not be exactly what your looking for.  However, if your files reside within the classpath, you may be able to use ClassLoader.getSystemResource("somefile.txt")...you also would no longer want to include the resources folder as stated above.  Another option would be to look in the jar's parent directory (or static path) for a given file (resource) and open them using File or some other equivalent to fit your needs.  If the file does not exist, create it from the resources stored within the jar.  They would be more like templates in this case.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked like I had images in `icons` folder under `src` and I wrote below code.

`new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/rsz_measurment_01.png"));`