# The report is not showing

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports

I have a problem with my report on project in *NetBeans*.

Why is my report cannot viewing while I execute my project.jar but there is no problem while I debug on *NetBeans*?

Here's the source code

```
File file = new File("**src/Report/TIKET.jrxml**");// is this the problem?
jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(file);
param.clear();
jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, param,cnn);
JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);
```

Comment: I assume that you added the `**` around the filename?  But indeed, when the file originally lived in src it's highly doubtful it got included in the final jar (a jar file is a zip file, you can inspect it with any tool you use to manipulate zips.

Comment: sorry i just try to bolding src/Report/TIKET.jrxml but i dunno why maybe it's autotext. but actually there is no ** in my project. ok got it thanks I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to ensure your jrxml gets packaged is to handle it as a resource, and load it this way:

```
jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(TheNameOfYourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("path-to/TIKET.jrxml"));
```

what `path-to` should be depends a bit on how you want to structure your project, see eg [How to correctly get image from 'Resources' folder in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845231/how-to-correctly-get-image-from-resources-folder-in-netbeans) where it's proposed to add a resources directory to src, so the final path would be "resources/TIKET.jrxml", but you can also store the jrxml eg in the default package (which represents the root of the package hierarchy).

Comment: thanks fvu sir, the problem has begone. also for my imageicon :D