# Adding folders to jars

Tags: java, netbeans

I created a folder called "res" in which I put all the sound files and picture files that my application uses. I added the folder to my project as a library so using

> "/filename.whatever"

as the filepath works when I run the project in netbeans.
However, when I try to clean and build it says:

> Not copying library path\res , it's a directory.

How do I get netbeans to put the folder in the jar so that it still works with the same filepath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the answer of the [SAM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1267661/sam)

This was a pain, using netBeans IDE 7.2.

1. You need to remember that Netbeans cleans up the Build folder whenever you rebuild, so
2. Add a resource folder to the **src** folder:

   - (project)

     - **src**

       - project package folder (*contains .java files*)
       - **resources**          (*whatever name you want*)
       - images (*optional subfolders*)
3. After the clean/build this structure is propogated into the Build folder:

   - (project)

     - build

       - classes

         - project package folder (*contains generated .class files*)
         - resources              (*your resources*)
         - images       (*your optional subfolders*)

To access the resources:

```
dlabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("**resources/images/logo.png**")));
```

and:

```
if (common.readFile(getClass().getResourceAsStream **("/resources/allwise.ini**"), buf).equals("OK")) {
```

worked for me. Note that in one case there is a leading "/" and in the other there isn't.
So the **root of the path to the resources** is the "**classes**" folder within the build folder.

Double click on the executable jar file in the dist folder. The path to the resources still works.

Src : [How to correctly get image from 'Resources' folder in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845231/how-to-correctly-get-image-from-resources-folder-in-netbeans)