# How to access resource files in Netbeans (Java)?

Tags: java, netbeans-8

There are two requirements,

- Locate and Run a .m (Octave script) using Java
- Take the output and use it in the program.

This is how my files are

I tried putting them in different folders and it didn't work.
[image: Files Structure]

This is how I want to use them.
[image: Code of Using files]

How do I access them in Netbeans IDE 8.2?

---

Edit for Clarification:
The presumed duplicate doesn't solve my problem. It tell us how to import an image. What I am doing here is running a script directly which is stored somewhere in my project files.

Comment: What is data.txt? Where is it located? Where do your `.class` files go? Using `./` would look in the current directory from where the program is run which is usually one level above the package structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correctly get image from 'Resources' folder in NetBeans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845231/how-to-correctly-get-image-from-resources-folder-in-netbeans)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the netbeans directory project structure, you need to create one **resources** directory. Then put your files there in resource directory.

Please update your code like below.

Put your file under /resources/, then use it like below.

```
ProcessBuilder pb= new ProcessBuilder("resources/ProcessImg.m");
Path data_file = Paths.get("resources/data.txt")
```