# Java Netbeans file packages

Tags: java, netbeans, package, filereader

I have the following example

package.one-which contains Map.java and a
maps.package containing map0.map

How do I call map0.map<--A text file from maps?

I have tried various different formats.

```
   //HardCoded mapname varient
   FileReader theFile = new FileReader("c:\\temp\\map0.map");
   //From c: temp
    //FileReader theFile = new FileReader("c:\\temp\\"+mapName);
```

this problem line-->FileReader theFile = new FileReader("maps\\"+mapName);

I have tried /maps/+mapName however it does not work 
mapName is passed into the function and will be dynamic.

**How do I call map0.map<--A text file from maps?**

Comment: I cant explain it well Iam not alowed images and text formating does not work as spaces are removed and everything does not line up.

Comment: Please refer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845231/how-to-correctly-get-image-from-resources-folder-in-netbeans) to know where to put your resource file and how to read it.

Comment: `Paths.get("maps/package/map0.map")`  should work fine from netbeans.