# Unable to getResources

Tags: java, spring

My Spring project test folder structure is as follow:

```
test/resources/spring/jobs

test/resources/testfiles/
```

My goal is to write file to testfiles folder

When I do the following, it returns me to the **build** path URL:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("spring/jobs")

/Users/xxx/Projects/test-project/build/resources/test/spring/jobs
```

However, when I do the following, it simply returns a null:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("testfiles")
```

I am writing test and my goal is to write files to the testfiles folder in the resources folder?

```
/Users/xxx/Projects/test-project/src/test/resources/testfiles/
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is likely a CLASSPATH issue - to debug it further- check this out [Debug getResource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253066/debugging-getresource)

Comment: May I suggest to use a `TemporaryFolder` junit rule (if using junit), writing to the resources **source** folder is not a good idea

Comment: see, you have `resources/test/spring/jobs` instead of `test/resources/spring/jobs`

Answer (score 3):

The resource path is not considered writable, so you simply shouldn't do this. Create a temporary directory instead.

(And the reason for the null return is that the directory itself isn't considered a resource and isn't usually available.)